# Arduino WiFiClient Write

Tags: c++, c++11, arduino

Как правильно, без объявления, переменной собрать строку?

serverClient.write(...)

```
#define MAX_SRV_CLIENTS 4

WiFiServer server(TELNET_PORT);
WiFiClient serverClients[MAX_SRV_CLIENTS];

void TelnetInit() {
  server.begin();
  server.setNoDelay(true);
}

void TelnetInput()
{
  uint8_t ClientID;
  ...
  if (server.hasClient()) {
    ...
    if (ClientID == MAX_SRV_CLIENTS) {
      WiFiClient serverClient = server.available();
      serverClient.write( "maximum " + MAX_SRV_CLIENTS + " of concurrent connections " );
      serverClient.stop();

    }
  }
}
```

при сборке вылетает ошибка

> serv.ino: In function 'void TelnetInput()':
>
> serv.ino:84:58: error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [25]' to binary 'operator+'
>
> serverClient.write( "maximum " + MAX_SRV_CLIENTS + " concurrent connections\n" );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно привести аргументы к типу, поддерживающему оператор `+` в нужной интерпретации. В частности можно было бы использовать `std::string`. Но из-за наличия числа, да и по сути формирования строки лучше использовать строковый поток `std::stringstream` или вовсе сишную `sprintf()`:

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream ss;

ss << "maximum " << MAX_SRV_CLIENTS << " concurrent connections\n";
```

`ss.str().c_str()` вернёт сишную строку, скорее всего нужную для `serverClient.write()`.

Если всё же хочется склеивать строку через `+`, то нужно как минимум как-то преобразовать число, которое приходит из макроса, в строку. Например, это можно сделать дополнительными макросами же:

```
#define xstr(a) str(a)
#define str(a) #a

auto s =  std::string("maximum ") + xstr(MAX_SRV_CLIENTS) + " concurrent connections\n";
```

Или, раз уж C++11 есть, то `std::to_string()`:

```
std::string("maximum ") + std::to_string(MAX_SRV_CLIENTS) + " concurrent connections\n";
```

Если не хочется заводить человеческую именованную переменную, и тем не менее нужно передать в функцию сишный указатель, то достаточно последнее выражение обернуть в скобки и вызвать для него `c_str()`:

```
(std::string("maximum ") + std::to_string(MAX_SRV_CLIENTS) + " concurrent connections\n").c_str()
```

Но с помощью макроса преобразования в строку и зная о конкатенации строковых литералов, записанных последовательно, можно действительно исключить использование переменной и создание временных строковых объектов:

```
"maximum " xstr(MAX_SRV_CLIENTS) " concurrent connections\n";
```

Стоит заметить, что никаких знаков `+` тут нет, и даже пробелы вокруг макроса `xstr` не являются обязательными.

Comment: ```MAX_SRV_CLIENTS``` - это же число. Сработает?

Comment: @isnullxbh пофиксил :)

Comment: так задача заключается в том чтоб не объявлять переменную ss

Comment: serverClient.write( sprintf( "Max %d", MAX_SRV_CLIENTS));
выдает ошибку
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
...
error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'

Comment: @Aleksey странное требование про отсутствие переменной, но тем не менее, привёл вариант.

Comment: спасибо огромное, а какие есть еще варианты склейки строк кроме знака плюс?

Comment: @Aleksey [strcat](http://cppstudio.com/post/695/)

Comment: @Aleksey, Вы не хотите объявлять лишнюю переменную, но не против того, что у Вас несколько раз вызывается конструктор для ```std::string```? :)

Comment: @isnullxbh отблагодарил чисто из вежливости. все таки пришлось объявить новую переменную ;)

Comment: @Aleksey чисто из вежливости добавил вариант конкатенации на стадии компиляции.